# How to set pagination at the bottom of a div?

Tags: php, css

I have a problem with my pagination style...
i want to set the pagination at the bottom of the div

[image]

now my pagination is look like this,i would like to set the pagination at the bottom of the div and the position of pagination will not be fixed,if i change the `result_per_page` to 10 or more the pagination will automatically adjust its position at the bottom

here is my pagination style

```
<style>
        .paginate {
            height:34px;
            position:relative;
            width:auto;
            display:inline-block;
        }

        .paginate a {
            padding:2px 5px 2px 5px;
            margin:2px;
            border:1px solid #999;
            text-decoration:none;
            color: #666;
        }
        .paginate a:hover, .paginate a:active {
            border: 1px solid #999;
            color:#0384DA
        }
        .paginate span.current {
            margin: 2px;
            padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
            border: 1px solid #0384DA;

            font-weight: bold;
            background-color: #0384DA;
            color: #FFF;
        }
        .paginate span.disabled {
            padding:2px 5px 2px 5px;
            margin:2px;
            border:1px solid #eee;
            color:#0384DA;
        }

        li{
            padding:4px;
            margin-bottom:3px;
            background-color:#FCC;
            list-style:none;}

        ul{margin:6px;
           padding:0px;}    

    </style>
```

Contents inside the body

```
    <body>
    <?php
    $targetpage = "pagnate.php";
    $limit = 10;
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblpropertyregister");
    $total_pages = mysql_num_rows($query);
    $stages = 3;
    if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] != '') {
        $page = $_GET['page'];
        $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;
    } else {
        $start = 0;
    }
    // Get page data
    $query1 = "SELECT * FROM tblpropertyregister LIMIT $start, $limit";
    $result = mysql_query($query1);
    // Initial page num setup
    if ($page == 0) {
        $page = 1;
    }
    $prev = $page - 1;
    $next = $page + 1;
    $lastpage = ceil($total_pages / $limit);
    $LastPagem1 = $lastpage - 1;
    $paginate = '';
    if ($lastpage > 1) {
        $paginate .= "<div class='paginate'>";
        // Previous
        if ($page > 1) {
            $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$prev'>previous</a>";
        } else {
            $paginate.= "<span class='disabled'>previous</span>";
        }
        // Pages    
        if ($lastpage < 7 + ($stages * 2)) { // Not enough pages to breaking it up
            for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++) {
                if ($counter == $page) {
                    $paginate.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                } else {
                    $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$counter'>$counter</a>";
                }
            }
        } elseif ($lastpage > 5 + ($stages * 2)) { // Enough pages to hide a few?
            // Beginning only hide later pages
            if ($page < 1 + ($stages * 2)) {
                for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($stages * 2); $counter++) {
                    if ($counter == $page) {
                        $paginate.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                    } else {
                        $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$counter'>$counter</a>";
                    }
                }
                $paginate.= "...";
                $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$LastPagem1'>$LastPagem1</a>";
                $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$lastpage'>$lastpage</a>";
            }
            // Middle hide some front and some back
            elseif ($lastpage - ($stages * 2) > $page && $page > ($stages * 2)) {
                $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=1'>1</a>";
                $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=2'>2</a>";
                $paginate.= "...";
                for ($counter = $page - $stages; $counter <= $page + $stages; $counter++) {
                    if ($counter == $page) {
                        $paginate.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                    } else {
                        $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$counter'>$counter</a>";
                    }
                }
                $paginate.= "...";
                $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$LastPagem1'>$LastPagem1</a>";
                $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$lastpage'>$lastpage</a>";
            }
            // End only hide early pages
            else {
                $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=1'>1</a>";
                $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=2'>2</a>";
                $paginate.= "...";
                for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($stages * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++) {
                    if ($counter == $page) {
                        $paginate.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                    } else {
                        $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$counter'>$counter</a>";
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Next
        if ($page < $counter - 1) {
            $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$next'>next</a>";
        } else {
            $paginate.= "<span class='disabled'>next</span>";
        }

        $paginate.= "</div>";
    }
    echo $total_pages . ' Results';
    // pagination
    echo $paginate;
    ?>

    <ul>

        <?php
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

            echo '<li>' . $row['PropertyTitle'] . "- -" . $row['PropertyCode'] . '</li>';
        }
        ?>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Post the rendered html code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could echo your pagination code after you echo out the table?

Remove 'echo $paginate;', and wrap it in php tags after the < /ul >

```
<?php echo $paginate; ?>
```